# Topology of level sets for meromorphic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds, percolation, meromorphic-functions

Let $F$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$.

I consider the "level set" $$E_\varepsilon=\{z:|F(z)|\leq\varepsilon\}.$$ My objective is to find conditions under which $E_\varepsilon$ does not percolate for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small, i.e. it has only bounded connected components. My function $F$ is not periodic nor a polynomial and has infinitely many zeros and poles.

Any idea of a helpful tool?

More specifically, I actually want to prove that "gradient lines" do not percolate in $E_\varepsilon$, where a gradient line is just a function $y(t)\in\mathbb{C},t\geq 0$ such that $y'(t)=F(y(t))$.

So for those who want a binary question: Are there non-periodic non-polynomial meromorphic functions such that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $F$ does not have unbounded gradient lines lying in $E_\varepsilon$?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is a "random and stationary meromorphic function"? What is your definition of a probability measure on the set of all meromorphic functions in C?

Comment: I just talked about "random meromorphic functions" to help understand the kind of assumptions I am talking about. To keep it simple, consider random meromorphic functions of the form $$F(z)=\sum_i 1/(z-z_i)$$ where the set $\{z_i;i\geq 1\}$ is a random stationary set of points (the random sum is not always well defined, but it is well defined in some sense in some cases, see for instance https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-007-0613-z)

Comment: In the paper you cite, the "random function" is ENTIRE, and of very special kind. No natural notion of randomness is known to me for MEROMORPHIC functions.

Comment: Ok I should have been more precise. I am not talking about $f$, if you go p.3 of the paper, the potential $\nabla U=\nabla [\log(|f(z)|)-|z|^2/2]$ can be seen as a random meromorphic function of the previous form. I am not interested by this particular function but this is an example of a random meromorphic function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The formula you wrote does not define a meromorphic function. Actually I consulted with one of the authors of that paper: he says that there is no reasonable definition of a random meromorphic function in the literature.

Comment: Interesting. I would be curious to understand why $\sum_i \frac(1}{z-z_i}$ is not meromorphic.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the input, but randomnes was not really the point of my question anyway.

Comment: Then please restate your question so that it makes some precise meaning.

Comment: Ok :) I removed any reference to randomness. Any tool that says something about the topology of level lines of meromorphic functions can be of use to me.

Comment: What does it mean "to find conditions"? What sort of conditions? In terms of what?

Comment: That is precisely the question. I put a binary question at the end if you think it is better to ask it like that.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I don't think the OP claims to have a definition of _the_ natural probability distribution on _all_ meromorphic functions. I think they just happen to define a random function that happens to be meromorphic on the plane and stationary. It is easy to construct such distributions, for instance by taking a random translate of a fixed elliptic function. I think the new question, although technically well-posed, is actually less illuminating: the initial question was more about if functions with unbounded gradient lines are in some sense "generic" or "rare".

Comment: Of course I am not claiming that anything interesting can be said in this level of generality, but in this case the critic would be that the level of generality of the question is too high, and I am not sure the OP can be blamed for not being aware of this fact. Especially given that they don't seem to be sure that such functions even exist, and my opinion (maybe as a young and naïve researcher who does not know the answer himself) is that this is not something to be ashamed about.

Comment: @Pierre PC: in either version, old or new, I do not see any well-defined question, to which a reasonable answer can be expected.

Comment: What about the last formulation?